# Method hangs when trying to assign value within event function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, client-server

I am creating a multiplayer game that has to communicate with a server. To communicate I have made a ClientObject that continuously waits for a message from the server. When a message is received, it deciphers what it is and sends out an event with the message. In the function that fires when the event has been broadcast, I try to assign part of the message to a PlayerObject. For example, the name of the other players. My issue is that when it reaches Players[i].Name = name[i] the program hangs. Debug shows that name[i] is the expected value. Player[i].Name is null at the point of assignment but is an available String variable so the line should work.

**Client Object:**

```
public class ClientObject
{
    public Socket clientSocket;
    public void Connect()
    {
        IPEndPoint serverAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.56.1"), 3000);

        clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientSocket.Connect(serverAddress);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessage));
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void ReceiveMessage() {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {

                byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[4];
                clientSocket.Receive(rcvLenBytes);
                int rcvLen = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(rcvLenBytes, 0);
                byte[] rcvBytes = new byte[rcvLen];
                clientSocket.Receive(rcvBytes);
                String rcv = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBytes);



                MessageReceivedEventArgs args = new MessageReceivedEventArgs();
                args.Message = rcv;

                if (TestMessageRecevied != null)
                {
                    TestMessageRecevied(this, args);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }


    public delegate void MessageHandler(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e);
    public event MessageHandler TestMessageRecevied;
}
    public class MessageReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

**Player Object:**

```
public class PlayerObject
{

    public string Name 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool ReadyState
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int DiceLeft
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

**Ready Menu:**

In this case I am assigning a PlayerObject.Name variable, but it also hangs if i try to change an images sprite, or the value of a text object within the UI. So seems to be an issue with assignment but cannot workout what. If I do an assignment in the Start() method, it works perfectly fine.

```
public class ReadyMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    ClientObject client;

    public GameObject backgroundPanel;
    public Sprite tick;
    public Sprite cross;

    Text pName;
    Image imgCheck;

    PlayerObject[] players;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pName = GameObject.Find("PlayerPanel1/Name").GetComponent<Text>();

        players = new PlayerObject[6];
        client = new ClientObject();
        client.TestMessageRecevied += Client_MessagedReceived;
        client.Connect();
        SendClientMessage(PlayerPrefs.GetString("name"));

    }

    private void Client_MessagedReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("In C_MR: " + e.Message);
        string message = e.Message;

        if (message.Contains("READY"))
        {
            //NOT IMPLEMENTED YET

            return;
        }
        if (message.Contains("PLAYERS"))
        {
            //Message before split
            Debug.Log(message);
            message = message.Substring(7);

            //Cut PLAYERS from the string
            Debug.Log("substring: "+message);

            //Seperate names
            char[] sep = { ' ' };
            String[] names = message.Split(sep,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Debug.Log("after name split");
            Debug.Log("names length is: "+names.Length);
            Debug.Log("names 0 is: "+names[0]);

            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) 
            {

                Debug.Log("in loop, i = "+i);

                Debug.Log("in loop, setting playerobject name");
                players[i] = new PlayerObject();
                players[i].Name = names[i];
                Debug.Log("in loop, after setting playerobject name");

                //GameObject panel = GameObject.Find("PlayerPanel" + (i + 1));
                //Debug.Log("in loop, activate apnel");
                //panel.SetActive(true);
            }
            Debug.Log("finsihed");
        }

    }
```

**Output with the name being test**

In C_MR: PLAYERStest

PLAYERtest

Substring: test

after split

names length is: 1

names 0 is: test

in loop, i = 0

in loop, setting playerobject name

Comment: Ah I see that you've added in that all-important line... Does it work now? I've tested the code for myself in a basic manner and it works fine. I'm unfamiliar with Unity, perhaps it isn't liking the fact that you're updating the `Name` property from a non-ui thread ? (Assuming that you are displaying the `Name` property in a UI) You may have to look into dispatching between threads

Comment: Also it would be nice if you'd leave a comment / update your question description to say you've made an edit that invalidates previous answers :)

Comment: Sorry I should have added a comment! I have added the line `players[i]=new PlayerObject()` within a for loop checking if `players[i]!=null` so as to only update it once. This has actually fixed this hang, but the issue still occurs if I assign something before it, for example `pName.text = "NameTest"` (initialised in start) this line if placed just before the `players[i].Name = names[i]`  works as expected but then causes the following line to hang. I am also new to Unity but it seems unlike android studio, it detects changes to UI objects and handles accordingly

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - It appears the OP has edited their answer to include the `players[i] = new PlayerObject()` statement, thereby invalidating this answer

---

Your issue is stemming from the fact that you haven't actually filled your `players` array with `PlayerObject`s. By only doing `PlayerObject[] players = new PlayerObject[6]`
you're just creating an array of six null objects.

Hence, when you try to access the `player.Name` property, you're trying to do so on a null object. This should throw a `NullReferenceException`, however you're masking any exceptions by using a `try-catch` within the `ReceiveMessage` function without actually catching and logging the exception.

Therefore, you just need to populate your `players` array with `PlayerObject`s, and you should be good to go. You could do that just before you you set the name (i.e. `players[i] = new PlayerObject()`), as long as name changes will only occur once in the application lifetime, or do it when you create the the `players` array.